# VS 2010 Could not resolve mscorlib for target framework. but only specific to 1 computer

Tags: visual-studio-2010

```
Could not resolve mscorlib for target framework '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0'. This can happen if the target framework is not installed
```

that's the error when i try to run the project. but it's only specific to my laptop. i tried it on my other laptop, runs fine. friend's laptop? also fine.

googling up some said the path is too long. nope, tried that, didn't matter.

anything else that you guys have in mind that might trigger this? or any ideas for what should i try doing?

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the following method to overcome the issue:

- Check if your the source folder is read-only
- Check that the target framework in the project properties is set correctly - by default this is ".Net Framework 4.0 Client" - it may be that you require ".Net Framework 4.0"
- Debug the issue using reflector by using the guidelines in http://traf-o-data.blogspot.com/2010/10/mystery-of-mscorlib.html?_sm_au_=iqVVNHv0V6tW6DSq
- I would suggest to run Fusion Log Viewer and check the error when trying to load `mscorlib` - using MSDN guide - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.110).aspx

I hope it supports your issue, please let me know..